# update user profile informations in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a profile page where user informations entered in registration page will be displayed, those inputs such email, username etc is displayed/echoed in input form fields so that the user can update or change it right away when he/she wants.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyQOZ.png)

And this is the code in the email input:

```
<form>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input name="address" type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Email" value="<?php  echo  $rows['address'];  ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is session.php that is included in profile.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();


$user_check = isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : '';
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($db,"select  username,mem_id  from  member  where  
username='$user_check'  ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$loggedin_session=$row['username'];
$loggedin_id=$row['mem_id'];

if(!isset($loggedin_session)  ||  $loggedin_session==NULL)
{
header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

I want to happen is, the user can be able to update his/her email just by changing the input value where his/her current email is displayed. All helps will be appreciated Thanks :).

Comment: what have you tried? give the input a name btw

Comment: sorry i forgot, name="address"

Answer (score 0):

Flesh out the form. Make the form post back to the page it's on, give the email field an id and give it a submit button.

Then at the top of the php code you can check whether the $_POST var has anything in it.

If it doesn't you can display the page as normal.

If it does, then you can set the users email equal to $_POST["idOfEmailField"]